# Doing something like Python's "import" in Scala

Tags: scala, import, include

Is it possible to use Scala's `import` without specifying a main function in an object, and without using the `package` keyword in the source file with the code you wish to import?

Some explanation: In Python, I can define some functions in some file "Lib.py", write

```
from Lib import *
```

in some other file "Run.py" in the same directory, use the functions from Lib in Run, and then run Run with the command `python Run.py`. This workflow is ideal for small scripts that I might write in an hour.

In Scala, it appears that if I want to include functions from another file, I need to start wrapping things in superfluous objects. I would rather not do this.

Comment: `#include` and `import` are just a little bit not the same.

Comment: what's wrong with using the `package` statement in your file?

Comment: @Erick Fleming, this is a stylistic issue more than a practical one. I don't need namespaces or OOP in my simple script, so I'd rather not have them forced upon me. Ultimately, it comes down to maybe two extra lines of code in my script, but these extra lines still bother me. I'll stop complaining now, and appreciate Scala for the things it does well ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing Python in Scala is unlikely to yield satisfactory results. Objects are not "superfluous" -- it's your program that is not written in an object oriented way.

First, methods must be inside objects. You can place them inside a `package object`, and they'll then be visible to anything else that is inside the package of the same name.

Second, if one considers solely objects and classes, then all package-less objects and classes whose class files are present in the classpath, or whose scala files are compiled together, will be visible to each other.

Comment: Thanks for your response, which I'm taking as a "no". It's correct that I'm talking about writing a simple script, not a more complicated program that would benefit from namespaces and ubiquitous OOP.

Answer (score 1):

This is as minimal as I could get it:

```
[$]> cat foo.scala
object Foo {
   def foo(): Boolean = {
      return true
   }
}

// vim: set ts=4 sw=4 et:
[$]> cat bar.scala
object Bar extends App {
    import Foo._

    println(foo)
}

// vim: set ts=4 sw=4 et:
[$]> fsc foo.scala bar.scala
[$]> export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH # Or else it can't find Bar.
[$]> scala Bar
true
```

Answer (score 0):

When you just write simple scripts, use Scala's REPL. There, you can define functions and call them without having any enclosing object or package, and without a main method.

Answer (score 0):

Objects/classes don't have to be in packages, though it's highly recommended. That said, you can also treat singleton objects like packages, i.e., as namespaces for standalone functions, and import their contents as if they were packages.

If you define your application as an object that extends App, then you don't have to define a main method. Just write your code in the body of the object, and the App trait (which extends thespecial DelayedInit trait) will provide a main method that will execute your code.

If just want to write a script, you can forgo the object altogether and just write code without any container, then pass your source file to the interpreter (REPL) in non-interactive mode.